# Automatically delete the formula once I get the value in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is that possible to do such a thing in excel?

I have been searching for many articles and videos

and all those are telling me to do it by hands

so, I wonder if there is any way to immediately delete the formula and keep the value? so that the links between the old and new value can be eliminated?

Like, I don't know, maybe =sum(A1:A5,del)

something like this?

Comment: With plain Excel it is not possible. However, if you click on the "record a macro" button at the low left corner, you would see a brand new world, where this is quite easy to achieve.

Comment: "I have been searching for many articles and videos and all those are telling me to do it by hands" - can you refer at least one video/book which is telling you so? I would love to see it.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ST9PIe9BDZI

Comment: I am new to StarckOverflow and I couldn't find a reply function at this moment
hope you see my rely

Comment: waiyiu9981 - the reply function comes if you put @ in front of my name. Like this - `@vityata`.

Comment: Well, the video is quite nice. If that guy learns VBA it would probably change his life for good.

Comment: @vityata  how about if I am using google excel. As my friend told me that vba cannot be used in google excel

Answer (score 2):

Is there any way to immediately delete the formula and keep the value?

**No**

However, you can do so with [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). This is quite a simple code, which would check whether the value of ActiveSheet of Range("A1") is more than 0. If it is, it saves the cell as a value and the formula disappears. Just be careful, you cannot use "Undo" once you run the code:

```
Sub DeleteValue()

    With ActiveSheet
        If .Range("A1").Value2 <> 0 Then
            .Range("A1").Value2 = .Range("A1").Value2
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well, work that in to a worksheet change event and you're there.

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor - in a way you are right, but showing events for someone who has never coded is quite tough I guess.

Comment: You are right there, I only left that column in response to the initial Q&A in case it was misleading to the OP. Still a good answer as always @Vityata

Answer (score 1):

Say, for example, we are entering items in column **C**.  If we enter a formula in a **C** cell, we want the formula to be automatically converted to value.  Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rInt As Range, r As Range, C As Range
    Set C = Range("C:C")
    Set rInt = Intersect(Target, C)

    If rInt Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rInt
            If r.HasFormula Then
                r.Value = r.Value
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

Automatically? No.

Manually? Yes.

Select the cell range where you want to delete the formulas and keep only the values, copy them, then right click -> Paste Special -> Values (V).

This will replace the cell formulas with the cell values that the formula calculated (at the moment you copied them).